# Langchain vectorstore for chat history

Tags: chatbot, openai-api, langchain, py-langchain, chromadb

I am trying to make a simple QA chatbot which is able to remember the past conversation and answer question about previous messages.

I use Chromadb as a vectorstore  to store the chat history and search relevant pieces of information when needed.

When I chat with the bot, it kind of remembers our conversation, but after a few messages, most of the time it becomes unable to give me correct answers about my previous messages.

Sometimes it can't even answer after one or two messages.

How can I improve this behaviour to be able to easily retrieve any piece of information at any time?

Here is my code:

```
chroma_client = chromadb.Client()
history_vectorstore = Chroma(client=chroma_client, embedding_function=embeddings)
retriever = history_vectorstore.as_retriever(search_kwargs=dict(k=2))
memory = VectorStoreRetrieverMemory(retriever=retriever, memory_key="chat_history", input_key="human_input")

template = """You are a chatbot having a conversation with a human.

{context}

{chat_history}

Human: {human_input}
Chatbot:"""

prompt = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["chat_history", "human_input", "context"], template=template
)
llm=OpenAI(temperature=1)memory_key="chat_history", input_key="human_input")
chain = load_qa_chain(
    llm, chain_type="stuff", memory=memory, prompt=prompt
)
```

Comment: this is probably limited by the model you are using with OpenAI (the default is 3.5 turbo, which is not fantastic handling context/history). Try with a different one from OpenAI (GPT4 for example) or use a different llm model (Gemini, Mistral, etc). Another approach could be to store the history in a vector store and use it in the chain.